# Creating appinstaller on Azure DevOps results in empty file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, msix

I'm creating an appinstaller file on Azure DevOps, but the file is empty (497 bytes). When I download it, change the extention to `.zip` and extract I get "the compressed (zipped) folder is empty".

Here's the relevant YAML (using the MSIX extension):

```yaml
- pwsh: dotnet build .\Sample\WinFormsApp\WinFormsApp.csproj

- task: MsixPackaging@1
inputs:
  outputPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/msix/MyApp.msix'
  solution: '.\Sample\WinFormsApp.MsixPackaging\WinFormsApp.MsixPackaging.wapproj'
  clean: false
  generateBundle: false
  buildConfiguration: 'debug'
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  updateAppVersion: false
  appPackageDistributionMode: 'SideloadOnly'
  msbuildLocationMethod: 'location'
  msbuildLocation: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'

- task: MsixSigning@1
inputs:
  package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\msix\MyApp.msix'
  certificate: 'SelfSignedCert.pfx'
  passwordVariable: 'password'

- task: AppInstallerFile@1
inputs:
  package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\msix\MyApp.msix'
  outputPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WinFormsApp.appinstaller'
  method: 'create'
  fileVersion: '1.0.0.0'
  uri: '\\host\path'
  mainItemUri: '\\host\path'
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

AppInstaller files are XML specifying URLs where a program and its dependencies can be acquired, not a ZIP. It's most likely that you'd find a well formed AppInstaller manifest by opening the file in notepad, as the non-zero size suggests it does have some contents into it.

[Here is an example of an AppInstaller file](https://github.com/TranslucentTB/TranslucentTB.github.io/blob/master/TranslucentTB.appinstaller)